# Migration from Delphi BDE - IBO or FIBPlus?

Tags: delphi, firebird, bde

I would like to know the better alternatives to the Delphi BDE. We have this huge application using Firebird 1.5 and BDE, and would like to consider the following alternatives:

1. IBObjects
2. FIBPlus

The migration will involve conversion to Firebird 2.5 dialect 3.

Can I get your ideas on which one is better? Your input is highly appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: have you considered TAdoQuery?

Comment: ADO does not support many of the Firebird specific features.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have never used IBObjects because I was quite happy with FibPlus. FibPlus datasets support interesting "separate transactions" feature that makes possible to write applications which are very similar to BDE applications but at the same time use Firebird transactions more effectively and support other Firebird specific features. I have written some beginner's [notes about using FibPlus](http://sergworks.wordpress.com/category/firebird/) that may be helpful as a starting point.

Comment: +1; FibPlus works really well. IBObjects development has been dormant for a while, but seems to be active again.

Comment: This conversion involves 893 forms and almost 2 million lines of code. For now I've installed FIBPlus trial version but whenever I try to connect using TpFIBDatabase I get the error "Trial version can't change library name". The gds32.dll is already copied to system32 folder. I've posted this error on the DevRace forum but until now no response from them.

Comment: @Princess Innah - I've never used FibPlus trial, but probably you should use fbclient.dll (located in Bin\ subfolder of the firebird installation directory) instead of gdi32.dll (gdi32 is for legacy applications, fbclient.dll is preferable for new applications)

Answer (score 0):

Both components are very good. Migrating from BDE will be easier with IBO, because it has components with the same property and methods names used in the "BDE" ones, and you can use the GReplace utility to change all the declarations from "BDE" to "IBO", ie: TQuery to TIBOQuery, etc. Check more info at http://www.ibobjects.com/ibo_help/convertbdetoibo.htm
Anyway, you should understand how IBO works to fine tune your application after the conversion.

It would be easier to migrate to FIBPlus if your app was using IBX instead of BDE.